# D3 change order of selection/appended svgs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a dot matrix visual as seen below in the snippet. Colored circles represent values and gray circles represent empty/unused. For instance, in my case, the three colors represent funding in percentage form for a project from 3 countries: USA, Canada and Mexico. The gray represents funding yet to be raised, also in percentage form.

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var data = [
  {'country':'USA', 'value':.20},
  {'country':'Canada', 'value':.15},
  {'country':'Mexico', 'value':.10}
];

var circArray = new Array(50);
var circPercentage = 100/circArray.length;

var circData = new Array;

data.forEach(function(item) {

  for (var i =0; i <item.value*100/circPercentage; i++) {
    circData.push(item.country);
}
});
var arrayDiff = 50-circData.length;
for (var i=0; i <(arrayDiff); i++) {
  circData.push("");
}

//console.log(circData)

var maxColumn = 10;

var colorMap = {
  'USA':"#f6d18b",
  'Canada':"#366092",
  'Mexico':"#95b3d7",
  "":"#a6a6a6"
};

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0,width])
    .domain([0,1]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height,0])
    .domain([0,1]);


graphGroup.selectAll('circle')
    .data(circData)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
        return (i % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
        return ~~((i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      //console.log(d)
      return colorMap[d];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

My use of `.forEach()` and my for loop work inasmuch that I created an array of the correct length to map the circles to the percentage logic, like so:

```
['USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA', ... , "", "", ""];
```

however I was unable to find documentation for which direction/order I want the circles to be appended. Supposed I wanted the opposite of the snippet above, where the the gray circles appear on top and the colored circles start from the bottom? Or suppose I wanted gray circles on the left and colored circles on the right?

### Question

Is there a straight-forward means to toggle the direction/order of svg elements? Or is my only option to transpose the data itself? As in:

```
["","","",... 'USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA'];
```

This approach bothers me, I don't know why. I'm hoping there is a slightly more sophisticated way.

Comment: isn't it the same order as `circData`? And I don't think order is even important in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **your code** it's the same order as `circData`.

But actually you control the position by `cx` and `cy`, not their order.

---

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var data = [
  {'country':'USA', 'value':.20},
  {'country':'Canada', 'value':.15},
  {'country':'Mexico', 'value':.10}
];

var circArray = new Array(50);
var circPercentage = 100/circArray.length;

var circData = new Array;

data.forEach(function(item) {

  for (var i =0; i <item.value*100/circPercentage; i++) {
    circData.push(item.country);
}
});
var arrayDiff = 50-circData.length;
for (var i=0; i <(arrayDiff); i++) {
  circData.push("");
}

circData.reverse() //<---------------------------

//console.log(circData)

var maxColumn = 10;

var colorMap = {
  'USA':"#f6d18b",
  'Canada':"#366092",
  'Mexico':"#95b3d7",
  "":"#a6a6a6"
};

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0,width])
    .domain([0,1]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height,0])
    .domain([0,1]);


graphGroup.selectAll('circle')
    .data(circData)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
        return (i % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
        return ~~((i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      //console.log(d)
      return colorMap[d];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```